# Accessing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits from inside Razor Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

In brief, I want to know how to access Blazor's `CircuitHandler` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits` from within a Razor component library.

I am trying to build a Razor Class Library that contains Blazor components, services, handlers, and some logic that are used for active user tracking. I have already implemented this code in a different Blazor server app, so I know that the approach works. I want to make it a generic and reusable library for my other projects.

However, I am running into a problem because one of my services in the library requires the namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits` to inherit from Blazor's CircuitHandler. When I try to add the `using` statement, I can't access the `Server.Circuits` namespace, and I'm getting an error:

`CS0234: The type or namespace name 'name' does not exist in the namespace 'namespace' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

I believe this is because the Razor Component Library is not a full Blazor app, so it might not have access to all of the same namespaces. I tried installing various NuGet packages to the component library, but none solve the problem. I don't know how to directly install the `Server.Circuits` namespace, or if it's even possible.

Is there a specific NuGet package I am missing, or a way to directly install the `Components.Server.Circuits` namespace to the Razor Component Library? Or alternatively, can I somehow pass the `CircuitHandler` into the component library when I register the services in `Program.cs` within the Blazor app?

Comment: Could you pls share a code snapshot?

Answer (score 2):

I asked about this on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/48290) and the dotnet team gave me an easy fix. You just need to add this line to an `ItemGroup` of your csproj:

```cs
<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server